# Meteor routing issue: Webhook returning HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, routes, iron-router

I am working on a Meteor application that must be able to listen to POST requests from an external API. To do so, I am trying to implement a Webhook where the API can send data that will later be stored in a Collection.

However, I am having trouble configuring the route and POSTing a basic header and message.

**My code (in /lib/routes.js):**

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
Router.route('/webhook', function(){

        var request = this.request;

        console.log("hook called");
        console.log("headers: ", request.headers);
        console.log("data: ", request.body);

        this.response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        this.response.write("You wrote: " + request.body);
        this.response.write("\n");

        this.response.end('Success!\n');
    }, {where: 'server'});
}
```

My request :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message":"foo"}' http://localhost:3000/webhook
```

The response I get in the console is a huge HTML page that has nothing to do with the request...

Any ideas as to where I made a mistake?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Greg

**Note:if I remove the `if(Meteor.isClient){...}` part, I get :**

> Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use
>   this.userId in publish functions.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `{where: 'server'}` option to your route config, you're telling Iron Router that this is a server side route. This means the route will only be accessible on the server. Wrapping this route definition in a `Meteor.isClient` check means that the route will only be defined when running client side (e.g. within a users browser). You can't define a server side route on the client side, so remove the `Meteor.isClient` check.

With regards to the `Meteor.userId` error you're getting when removing the `Meteor.isClient` check, the two are likely not related (since you're not referencing `Meteor.userId` anywhere in the sample you posted). Disable all other parts of your router config and just test this webhook by itself; it will work as expected (after removing `Meteor.isClient`).

Comment: I removed the Meteor.isClient check, and still had the error. If I only kept this route however it would work properly like you said ! I fixed the whole router by adding a !Meteor.isServer check to all the Meteor.userId() calls I had in my router, and it worked perfectly ! Thanks for your insight, I understand better how the whole thing works now.